# Search list of Facebook friends

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, list, codeigniter

I am trying to search a user's Facebook friends list against entries in a `gamers` table in an application database.

The `gamers` table looks like `id, name, points`. Eg. g_id-234567, name-john Smith, points-45. In this table a person's `id`, is actually their Facebook id.

I am using the following code in my Codeigniter application with the Facebook php sdk to return list of friends for the logged in user.

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

 foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {

                echo $value['id'];
}
```

This code is in my `index` function of my controller, and it successfully echos the ids of all the friends of the logged in user.

How do I check if any of my Facebook friends `id` matches that of any gamer `g_id` in my `gamers` table.

I want to get the list of `gamers` who are my Facebook friends, and order this list in descending order of points witha limit of 20. This is to get the top 20 Facebook friends gamers.

I would like to use this list of the logged in user's top 20 Faccebook friends in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (If you are using mysqli)

```
    $id = -1;
    $list = array();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT  * FROM gamers where id = ? ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 20");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    foreach($friends["data"] as $value) {
          $id = $value['id'];  
          $stmt->execute();
          $res = $stmt->get_result();
          array_push($list,$res->fetch_row());
     }
```

I hope, `$list` should contain the list of all facebook gamers.

Alternatively, you can use :

```
     $friends_set = '(';
     foreach($friends["data"] as $value) {
         $friends_set .= $value['id'].','; 
     }
     $new_set = preg_replace('/,$/',')',$friends_set);
     $res = mysql_query("SELECT * from gamers WHERE id IN $new_set ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 20");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
          //do your stuff
      }
```

Inside last loop you may traverse list of facebook gamers.

Comment: I tried `$friends_set = '(';
     foreach($friends["data"] as $value) {
         $friends_set .= $value['id'].','; 
     }
     $new_set = preg_replace('/,$/',')',$friends_set);
     $res = mysql_query("SELECT * from user WHERE id IN $new_set ORDER BY points LIMIT 10");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
          //do your stuff
      echo $row->fb_id;

      }`

Comment: But I got an error "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Comment: How do I get the id and name of users from the `gamers` table in the while loop?

Comment: You should use `select * from gamers` as your table name is `gamers` not `user`.

Comment: To get the name of gamers, use the associate array `$row['id']` and `$row['name']`.

Comment: $friends_set = '(';
     foreach($friends["data"] as $value) {
         $friends_set .= $value['id'].','; 
     }
     $new_set = preg_replace('/,$/',')',$friends_set);
     $res = mysql_query("SELECT * from gamers WHERE id IN $new_set ORDER BY points LIMIT 10");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
          //do your stuff
      echo $row['id'];

      }

Comment: still got the error "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Comment: Actually it was just a small typo on my end. Thanks